Upgrade to Ubuntu 24.10 made Chrome content look very odd. Colors are inverted
I upgraded my Ubuntu desktop to the latest version 24.10 a few days ago.
Now my system runs on 24.10, and all seemed to be fine.
After reboot I opened Chrome (version 130), and the colors somehow are inverted somehow, e.g. the Ask Ubuntu webpage looks like this:

The interesting is that when I take a screenshot (like above) and paste it into a Chrome window, the colors are correct. When pasting it to Gimp the colors are incorrect.
I googled a little and found some posts about inverted colors, but nothing related to my situation I believe.
I cleaned the .config/google-chrome/ directory but that didn't help
It's strange to me that other apps look fine with respect to colors.
